# countChars - So close, yet so far

Tags: java

I feel like I am almost there, I've just starred blind after trying everything I know(which isn't a lot.)

Alright, so I am trying to input a String that my method should read and give me the numbers of each character or even just the first. But I'm lost. Please help.

```
public class Sam {


private static String countChars;



public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(countChars);

}

static int countChars(String str, char searchChar) {

    // Count the number of times searchChar occurs in
    // str and return the result.
    int i;     // A position in the string, str.
    char ch;   // A character in the string.
    int count; // Number of times searchChar has been found in str.
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        ch = str.charAt(i);  // Get the i-th character in str.
        if (ch == searchChar) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

}

Best regards,
Sam

Comment: You're not calling `countChars()`. You're just printing an empty variable with the same name.

Comment: `System.out.println(countChars("this is it", 'i'));` this should be like this.

Comment: Don't learn programming by trial and error. You should read a java programming book.

Comment: I am. Maybe I should ask after I've read it all, but it's a bit long and I'm excited. :D

Comment: Hi @Sam, this is not a good title for your question. If you want to avoid getting mass downvoted, please put a clear title that correctly identifies your actual issue next time.

Comment: Heard. What would be a better title?

Answer (score 1):

You are not correctly calling the `countChars()` function in your `main()` function.

You could use the following for example

```
System.out.println(countChars("Hello, World", 'o'));
```

Comment: Already there learning something new that I can put the method name into the System.out.println. :D Thank you so much! 

What if I want to be able to put in a line and have to print it out for each letter? Or is that too much to ask for?